# Read RFCTable data using BAPI from SAP in C#

Tags: c#, sap-dotnet-connector

I want to read the table data from RFCtable in c# , I am able to get the table structure but I am not getting the data in the table.

Below is the code for that

```
                RfcDestinationManager.RegisterDestinationConfiguration(config__);
                RfcDestination prdData = RfcDestinationManager.GetDestination("Vim Analytics");
                RfcRepository repos = prdData.Repository;
                IRfcFunction InvoiceVIMAny = repos.CreateFunction("BAPI NAME");
               
                InvoiceVIMAny.SetValue("I_INVOICE_NO", InvoiceNumber);
                InvoiceVIMAny.SetValue("I_VENDOR_ID", VendorID);
               
                InvoiceVIMAny.Invoke(prdData);
                if (InvoiceVIMAny.ElementCount > 0 && InvoiceVIMAny.ElementCount != null)
                {
                    IRfcTable rfcTable = InvoiceVIMAny.GetTable(0);
                   
                    foreach (IRfcStructure dataRow in rfcTable)
                    {
                        invstatusResp.E_STATUS = dataRow.GetValue("E_STATUS").ToString();
                        invstatusResp.E_DOC_ID = dataRow.GetValue("E_DOC_ID").ToString();
                        invstatusResp.E_PO_NUMBER = dataRow.GetValue("E_PO_NUMBER").ToString();
                        invstatusResp.E_INVOICE = dataRow.GetValue("E_INVOICE").ToString();
                        invstatusResp.E_REASON = dataRow.GetValue("E_REASON").ToString();
                        invstatusResp.E_DOC_DATE = dataRow.GetValue("E_DOC_DATE").ToString();
                        invstatusResp.E_POSTING_DATE = dataRow.GetValue("E_POSTING_DATE").ToString();
                        invstatusResp.E_ENTRY_DATE = dataRow.GetValue("E_ENTRY_DATE").ToString();
                        invstatusResp.E_DUE_DATE = dataRow.GetValue("E_DUE_DATE").ToString();
                        invstatusResp.E_GROSS_AMT = dataRow.GetValue("E_GROSS_AMT").ToString();
                        invstatusResp.E_COMMENTS = dataRow.GetValue("E_COMMENTS").ToString();
                        invstatusResp.E_CUR_ROLE = dataRow.GetValue("E_CUR_ROLE").ToString();
                        listinvstatusResp.Add(invstatusResp);
                    }
                }
                RfcDestinationManager.UnregisterDestinationConfiguration(config__);
```

Comment: For me it seems that you've implemented everything correctly (I implement things in the same way). Ara you sure that there's everything okay on the "SAP side" ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Fetch the value of nested structure returned by RFC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24133940/fetch-the-value-of-nested-structure-returned-by-rfc)